# Cassandra compaction strategy for data that is updated frequently during the day

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

In my use case I have data that will be updated frequently during one day after its insertion and after that will be used rarely for reads only. What would be the best compaction strategy for that? TWCS or DTCS?

Answer (score 1):

TWCS was created because DTCS requires a lot of tuning and operational care in order to achieve & maintain good performance. TWCS provides a similar level of performance to DTCS and is much easier to work with, so it is definitely the one to use for 99% of cases where time-series data is involved and there will be no inserts/updates after the first window.

Take a look at [CASSANDRA-9666](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9666) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Twcs is the best compaction strategy for time serious data if you have frequent updates with less number of reads .

http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/12/08/TWCS-part1.html